# EF Code First Migration modelBuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two Entities in my C# code:

```
  public class Currency
{        
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CurrencyRate> CurrentCurrencyRates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CurrencyRate> TargetCurrencyRates { get; set; }
}

 public class CurrencyRate
    {
        public int RateID { get; set; }
        public DateTime RateDate { get; set; }
        public Decimal RateValue { get; set; }
        public int CurrentCurrencyID { get; set; }
        public int TargetCurrencyID { get; set; }


        public virtual Currency CurrentCurrency { get; set; }
        public virtual Currency TargetCurrency { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have Context Class:

```
public EconomicAppContext()
            : base("EconomicApp")
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyRate>().Property(v => v.RateValue).HasColumnType("Money");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyRate>().HasKey(cr => cr.RateID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasKey(c => c.CurrencyID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().
                HasMany<CurrencyRate>(c => c.CurrentCurrencyRates).
                WithRequired(c => c.CurrentCurrency).
                HasForeignKey(c => c.RateID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().
               HasMany<CurrencyRate>(c => c.TargetCurrencyRates).
               WithRequired(c => c.TargetCurrency).
               HasForeignKey(c => c.RateID);

             base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<CurrencyRate> CurrencyRates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to do migration into existing DB. I wanna to get schema something like this :

[image]

And what I'm doing wrong? May anybody help me to migrate tables into DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyRate>().
                HasRequired<Currency>(c => c.CurrentCurrency).
                WithMany(c => c.CurrentCurrencyRates).
                HasForeignKey(c => c.CurrentCurrencyID);
modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyRate>().
               HasRequired<Currency>(c => c.TargetCurrency).
               WithMany(c => c.TargetCurrencyRates).
               HasForeignKey(c => c.TargetCurrencyID);
```

Comment: Thaks! I've understood know!

Comment: @AlexGurskiy Welcome. Not sure what you did understand but that was because you were trying to create two relationship on one foreign key. :)

Comment: Yes. I've understood it. And now I have two tables tables ))